# How to Reduce prime factor vector<int > to map<int,int> in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, prime-factoring

I know how to find prime factors of a given numbers.

I store them in a vector of integers.

Like : prime_factor(2048)

Gives:

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

I want the solution in format of key and value pair using map

Like:

prime_factor(2048)

Gives: (2:11)

The key must be the prime number and value must be its occurrence in prime number.

Here is my code which return me a vector:

```
vector<int> primefactor(int n)
{vector<int> arr;
while(n%2==0)
    {
    n/=2;
    arr.push_back(2);
    }

int i=3;
    while(i*i<=n)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
    {   

    arr.push_back(i);
    n=n/i;
    }
    i+=2;
    }
if(n>2)
    {
    arr.push_back(n);
    }
return arr;
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried to achieve the desired behavior? And regarding the sample output: 25 and 125 are no prime-factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with `map<int,int>` as your result, you could replace `push_back(i)` with `res[i]++` to get the output that you need:

```
map<int,int> res;
while ( n%2 == 0 ) {
    n/=2;
    res[2]++;
}
...
```